# Remove the image tag when image is not uploaded to Channel Advisor. No jQuery method please

Tags: javascript, image, tags, channel, jssor

I am designing a template in Channel Advisor for an eBay store and it doesn't allow jQuery.
I used JSSOR (non-jQuery one) for my slider in order to make it responsive and swipe/touch friendly.

When I use template tags in  like:

```
<img src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL1}}"/>
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL1)}}"/>
```

I have 10 of {{ITEMIMAGEURL1}} and {{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL)}} tags number from 1-10 in the slider template, {{ }} are the image paths from Channel Advisor. In order to have this gallery work on all current listings, I need to delete some of the div tags correspond to how many images an ad has/uploaded to channel advisor.

Lets say I have this:

```
<div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL1}}">
    <img u="thumb" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL1)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage2" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL2}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail2" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL2)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage3" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL3}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail3" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL3)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage4" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL4}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail4" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL4)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage5" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL5}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail5" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL5)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage6" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL6}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail6" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL6)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage7" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL7}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail7" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL7)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage8" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL8}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail8" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL8)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage9" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL9}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail9" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL9)}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img u="image" id="galleryImage10" src="{{ITEMIMAGEURL10}}">
    <img u="thumb" id="thumbnail10" src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL10)}}">
    </div>
    </div>
```

and a listing has only 4 sets of pictures/first 4 sets image paths. How do I delete the div tags that wrap around the images from 5-10?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ...

```
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL1)}}" id="img1">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL2)}}" id="img2">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL3)}}" id="img3">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL4)}}" id="img4">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL5)}}" id="img5">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL6)}}" id="img6">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL7)}}" id="img7">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL8)}}" id="img8">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL9)}}" id="img9">
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL10)}}" id="img10">

function removeImages(site_has) {
  for (var i=site_has+1; i<=10; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img'+i).style.visibility='hidden';
  }
}
```

... to remove ...

```
var image_x = document.getElementById('img'+i);
image_x.parentNode.removeChild(image_x);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But if I am not understanding it wrong, this will hide/remove images from 1-10. Is there a way to detect and keep the image tags where the images are uploaded in Channel Advisor?